# How to get the current rowindex of gridview containing webcontrols

Tags: c#, asp.net

Need some clarification. I am using a gridview with enough no of rows and columns.
At footer, I've a button to add new row in gridview. My gridview consists of input controls like radiobutton, textboxes, etc.

My doubt is : I've a radiobuttonlist in all rows in gridview and when I click the listitem in radiobuttonlist, I need to know that which row(ROWINDEX) the radiobuttonlist was selected for some requirement.

I used this code

```
int rowIndex=gv.SelectedIndex;
```

I clicked the radiobutonlist at 5th row and rowIndex returns -1.

Comment: Can you add your markup to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `SelectedIndexChange` event of the `RadioButtonList` do:

```
void Index_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
{
   var rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)((WebControl)sender).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
}
```